# my binary file is always empty when i try to fill it with an array

Tags: arrays, c, binaryfiles

```
typedef struct equipement_agricole{
char type[20];
char marque[20];
char modele[20];
char numero_serie[30];
char panne[20];
char status[20];
int nb_status;
int nb_panne;
}equipement_agricole;
typedef struct eq_util{
    char numero_s[30];
    char type_u[20];
    char marque_u[20];
    char modele_u[20];
    int nb_util;
    int ordre;
}eq_util;
typedef struct verif{
    char id[30];
    int nb;
}verif

void equipement_plus_util()
{
    FILE *f;
    FILE *g;
    int i=0;
    int taille=0;
    f=fopen("equipement.bin","rb");
    g=fopen("equipement_util.bin","wb");
    equipement_agricole E;
    eq_util U;
    while(fread(&E,sizeof(equipement_agricole),1,f)!=0)
    {
        taille+=1;
    }
    verif tab1[taille];
    while(fread(&E,sizeof(equipement_agricole),1,f)!=0)
    {
        strcpy(tab1[i].id,E.numero_serie); 
        tab1[i].nb=E.nb_status;
          i++;
    }
    int j,k;
    verif T;
    for(j=0;j<taille-1;j++)
    {
        for(k=j+1;k<taille;k++)
        {
            if(tab1[j].nb<tab1[k].nb)
            {
                strcpy(T.id,tab1[j].id);
                T.nb=tab1[j].nb;
                strcpy(tab1[j].id,tab1[k].id);
                tab1[j].nb=tab1[k].nb;
                strcpy(tab1[k].id,T.id);
                tab1[k].nb=T.nb;
            }
        }
    }
    int a; 
    for(a=0;a<taille;a++)
    {
        while(fread(&E,sizeof(equipement_agricole),1,f)!=0)
        {
            if(strcmp(tab1[a].id,E.numero_serie)==0)
            {
                strcpy(U.marque_u,E.marque);
                strcpy(U.modele_u,E.modele);
                strcpy(U.numero_s,E.numero_serie);
                strcpy(U.type_u,E.type);
                U.nb_util=E.nb_status;
                U.ordre=a+1;
                fwrite(&U,sizeof(eq_util),1,g);
            }
        }
    }
  fclose(f);
  fclose(g);
  
}
```

hi guys i need your help i've been stuck in this sccince 2 days i can't find a solution for this so my problem is
after i take the necessair information from `equipement.bin` bianry file  and put it inside an array than i sort that array after that i put the array whit is i think sorted in the `equipement_util.bin` but i always find that it is always empty i tried every thin that i know thank you

Comment: Please check the return values from `fopen` and `fread`. Check `fopen` is not returning `NULL` and `fread` check for !=0 is not appropriate.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger to step through your code. It should show you that the second `fread` never reads anything and that `while` loop is never entered into. This is because after the first loop the file pointer is already at the end of the file. Use `rewind` to go back to the start. But reading the file twice is inefficient. Use `fseek` and `ftell` to get the file size and from that you can calculate the number of records.

Comment: @kaylum do you mean whhen i read from a binary file twice it takes the  pointer `&E` from where first time is left ?

Comment: Every time you call `fread` it reads from the current file position and then moves the file position. So after the first `fread` loop the file position is at the end of the file. Then when you call `fread` again it can't read anything since it is already at the end of the file.

Comment: regarding; `typedef struct verif{
    char id[30];
    int nb;
}verif`  This is missing the final semicolon `;` so does not compile\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
while(fread(&E,sizeof(equipement_agricole),1,f)!=0)
{
    taille+=1;
}
verif tab1[taille];
while(fread(&E,sizeof(equipement_agricole),1,f)!=0)
```

When the first 'while()' loop exits, the 'file pointer' will be at the end of the file, So the second `while()` loop will exit immediately.

To fix this problem:

after the first `while()` loop exits, reset the 'file pointer' to the beginning of the file.  Suggest:

```
rewind( f );
```

the above will result in the data from the file being set into the array `tab1[]`

There may be other problems, however  the above correction will get your code started in the right direction